# Your Visual does not appear to filter outwards to other visuals error raised by power bi custom visual validators

Tags: typescript, d3.js, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am developing a custom power bi visual and trying to get it certified but I keep on getting this issue **"Your Visual does not appear to filter outwards to other visuals"** raised by the validators.

I am trying to develop a simple custom power bi visual which consists of 4 charts: bar chart, column chart, stacked bar chart and stacked column chart. Can somebody explain to me here what does this statement **"Your Visual does not appear to filter outwards to other visuals"** mean and how I can resolve it. I am also trying to add **selection feature** to my visual. I have made appropriate changes in the code as explained in the documentation for adding selection feature to my chart which uses **category data view mapping** but it still fails to interact with other charts in the page. Can somebody explain what wrong I am doing here and how I can correct it. I am attaching the repo link here: [Multi-Charts-Custom-Power-BI-Visual](https://github.com/imparthv/Multi-Charts-Custom-BI-Visual)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Developer/Trying-to-filter-data-in-custom-visual/td-p/369949

Comment: Thanks Sam. Can you explain me what does this statement Your visual does not appear to filter outwards to other visuals mean? Validators have not provided any description other this statement in the issue report.

Comment: I believe it means that your visual is not informing other visuals of any selection(s) made to allow for cross-filtering. See row 11 on [General test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/submission-testing#general-test-cases)

Comment: I am trying to resolve the issue related to selection of the elements in my custom visual and trigger the other visuals to display data pertaining to selected data point but it is not working out as expected. While selection in the other visuals do affect my visual, I am not able to do it with my visual. I have referred the selection documentation as provided and since my visual uses categorical data view mapping I have made the changes as provided in the documentation but to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried the two steps outlined in the answer https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Developer/Trying-to-filter-data-in-custom-visual/td-p/369949 ?

Comment: I have made changes to the capabilities file as mentioned in the answer. However I am not able to find the selectionManager.applySelectionFilter() function in the documentation and I have doubts regarding where should I place it. Below here is my selectionManager code.

Comment: .on("click", (d) => {
                this.selectionManager.select(d.selectionID).then((selectionId: ISelectionId[]) => {
                    svg.selectAll(".bar").style({
                        "fill-opacity": selectionId.length > 0 ?
                            d => selectionId.indexOf(d.identity) >= 0 ? 1.0 : 0.5 :
                            1.0
                    } as any);
                });
            });